# How to connect to Azure Centos to change ifcfg-eth0

Tags: centos, azure

I accidentally changed `bootproto` to `none` from `dhcp` without specifying the static IP Address. After restarting the vm, I am not able to connect to the static IP. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I tested it in my lab. Mounting the OS disk from the VM exhibiting the problem to a working VM could solve this problem.

Please refer to the steps below.

1.Create a new VM A in the same VNet.

2.Stop the problem VM B and copy the OS VHD.

More information about copy OS VHD please refer to the following article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/

3.Delete VM B and keep the attached disks.

4.Once the lease is cleared, “Attach disk” from VM A to VM B via the Azure Portal

5.Mount the disk on VM A

> mkdir -p /mountpoint
>
> mount /dev/sdc /mountpoint

6.Modify ifcfg-eth0

> sed -i "s/BOOTPROTO=none/BOOTPROTO=dhcp/g"
>   /mountpoint/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

7.Umount the disk on VM A

> umount /mountpoint

8.Detach disk from VM  B via the management portal

9.Recreate the original VM by using templates

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-from-specialized-vhd

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Regards,

Walter